# Reference in element of the array another element of the same array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a possibility to reference an element of an array in another element with the same array?

Let's say we want to make an array like this:

```
$a = array(
    'base_url' => 'https://rh.example.com',
    'URL_SLO_OpenAM_OIC' => 'https://openam.example.com/openam/UI/Logout?goto='.$this['base_url'],
);
```

Of course, it doesn't work because `$this` is intended for classes not for arrays. So is there an alternative?

Comment: why are you using $this? Are you using it in the scope of a class?

Comment: No, I wanted just to explain what I want to mean by reference. the array isn't in a scope of a class.

Comment: Still, you should not be using the keyword $this (because it represent an object), you can't represent it as an array.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. See my update and tell me if my question is now more understandable?

Comment: How is that logically correct? a variable calling it self within it self? You don't need a computer science degree to know that.

Comment: I think that violates the concept of an array which is for objects capability

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it's not possible that way. You can't reference to the same array within its context. But here is a work around:

```
$a = array(
    'base_url' => ($base_url = 'https://rh.example.com'),
    'URL_SLO_OpenAM_OIC' => 'https://openam.example.com/openam/UI/Logout?goto='.$base_url,
);
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to add elements to array one by one.

```
$a['base_url'] = 'https://rh.example.com';
$a['URL_SLO_OpenAM_OIC'] = 'https://openam.example.com/openam/UI/Logout?goto='.$a['base_url'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not reference an array element to another element. Array dose not have such functionality. It will gives you an undefined variable error if you are doing this.
Answer to your question, you can store the value to an another variable and use that variable while initializing an array.

```
$base_url = 'https://rh.example.com';
$a = array(
'base_url' => $base_url,
'URL_SLO_OpenAM_OIC' => 'https://openam.example.com/openam/UI/Logout?goto='.$base_url,);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want with arrays because they are only data. But you can do this with an object:

```
$myCustomArray = new stdClass;
$myCustomArray->base_url = 'https://rh.example.com';
$myCustomArray->URL_SLO_OpenAM_OIC = function () { echo 'https://openam.example.com/openam/UI/Logout?goto='.$this->base_url; };
```

and then do : `$myCustomArray->URL_SLO_OpenAM_OIC();`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to substitute values after assignment, using tokens for simple cases.

```
<?php

function substitutor(array $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if(preg_match('/@(\w+)@/', $value, $match)) {
            $array[$key] = str_replace($match[0], $array[$match[1]], $value);
        } 
    };

    return $array;
}

$array = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => 'some' . '@foo@'
);

var_dump($array);
$substituted = substitutor($array);
var_dump($substituted);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  ["baz"]=>
  string(9) "some@foo@"
}
array(2) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  ["baz"]=>
  string(7) "somebar"
}
```