# In PHP is there a way of using a value from an array within itself?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

In this associative array I want to use the value from the first column for calculation in the second column within the same array.

```
$AMOUNTS = array(           
array('amount' => '10',  'price' => $AMOUNTS[0]['amount'] * 3 ),         
array('amount' => '50',  'price' => $AMOUNTS[1]['amount'] * 2 ),   
array('amount' => '70',  'price' => $AMOUNTS[2]['amount'] * 1 )
);
```

Comment: Your question does not make much sense: You have the amounts (10, 50, 70) and the factors (3, 2, 1) hardcoded, so why not hardcode the result of the multiplication also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't refer to the array until after the assignment is completed. You can add the `price` values in a separate step.

```
$AMOUNTS = array(           
    array('amount' => '10'),         
    array('amount' => '50'),   
    array('amount' => '70')
);

foreach ($AMOUNTS as $i => &$amount) {
    $amount['price'] = $amount['amount'] * (3 - $i);
}
```

You can see some other solutions in [Reference in element of the array another element of the same array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788131/reference-in-element-of-the-array-another-element-of-the-same-array/36788667#36788667)

Comment: What you suggested is what I'm doing right now but I was hoping that there is a better way.

Comment: I added a link to another question that has alternatives.